# Installing Oauth on CentOS

Tags: magento, oauth, oauth-2.0, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I am on CentOS. In magento, for converting the list of data to JSON format i came to know that intially i required to install oauth for consumer side. for installing oauth on centOS, I followed as suggested in this site : http://coolbung.blogspot.in/2010/04/installing-oauth-on-centos-54.html

but i am facing a problem when giving a command 'pecl install oauth-beta'. It shows that pecl command not found.

How can i get reslove of this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue this command to issue PHP Pear first:

```
yum install php-pear
```

Reference: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/install-php-pecl-centos/

Comment: Do u have any idea in magento to send JSON data using rest URL?? By using rest client we can only see the data in rest client?? But how can we take the output of data as json format using rest client??

Comment: please ask it in a separate question.